# Проверка существования цепочки ключей в массиве

Tags: php

Пишу функцию. Единственный параметр у нее - строка вида `fields;City;Moscow;active`

Функция в результате неких действий получает массив вида

```
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [City] => Array
                    (
                        [Moscow] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => 0
                            )

                        [Kazan] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => 0
                            )

                        [Voronezh] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => 1
                            )

                    )
            )
```

Вопрос: как мне узнать, существует ли в полученном функцией массиве цепочка ключей, пришедшая параметром? Как наиболее корректно и грамотно сделать это?

Comment: предоставьте код функции, так будет легче понять вопрос

Comment: Считаю это не целесообразным, на мой взгляд вопрос предельно ясен

Comment: извиняюсь я не правильно понял вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function issetChain($array, $keys, $delimeter = ';'){
   if (is_string($keys)) $keys = explode($delimeter, $keys);

   foreach ($keys as $key){
       if (isset($array[$key]))  $array = $array[$key];
       else return false;
   }

   return true;
}


$array = [
   'field' => [
       'two' => [
           'three' => [
               'ololo' => 'ololollolo'
           ]
       ]
   ]
];

$exists_keys = 'field;two;three;ololo';
$not_exists_key = 'test;any;city;street';

var_dump(issetChain($array, $exists_keys, ';')); // bool true
var_dump(issetChain($array, $not_exists_key, ';')); // bool false
```

Comment: хорошее решение и компактное, не погрязнув в циклах и парсингах Спасибо большое

Comment: В laravel в коллекциях видел подобный подход, самому было интересно разобраться как это работает :)

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет функция isset:

```
$array["fields"] =  array("City" =>array("Moscow"=>array("active"=>0),
                                         "Kazan"=>array("active"=>0),
                                         "Voronezh"=>array("active"=>1)));



if (isset($array["fields"]["City"]["Moscow"]["active1"])){
    print("OK");
}
else {
    print("BAD");
}
```

Comment: а если данные динамичные? что скорее всего так и есть.

Comment: Разумеется динамические, иначе isset и никаких вопросов :)